# how to adjust code to use backtracking algorithm to solve combination issue

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

Problem describe:

Return all combinations of a array. for example, there is an array [1, 2, 3], its results is:

```
[]
[1]  [2]  [3]
[1, 2]  [1, 3]  [2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Yes I know there are lot of ways to solve this. but I am trying to solve it with backtracking algorithm. below is my code:

```
def p(arr):
    ret = []
    #using visited boolean array to avoid duplicate traverse and backtracking.
    visited = [False] * len(arr)
    def dfs(start_idx, temp)
        ret.append(temp)
        for i in range(start_idx, len(arr)):
            if not visited[i]:
                visited[i] = True
                dfs(start_idx + 1, temp + [arr[i]])
                visited[i] = False
    dfs(0, [])
    return ret
```

It returns `[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3], [3, 2]]`, which has a wrong answer `[3, 2]`

From my understanding, dfs + backtracking should only traverse the array in one direction which is left to right. but clearly [3, 2] is the reverse direction.

How to understand this and how to fix this with my code?

Comment: Use `itertools.combinations`.

Comment: haha, sure. that's kind of ways:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm uses a list of booleans to keep track of what elements are selected. But that is not the good way to do it: once you selected an element *i*, you should make sure that you can only select elements with an index *j > i*.

You seem to do this with `start_idx`, but actually in the recursive call you *only increment `start_idx`.

So a quick fix is to set `start_index` to `i+1`:

```
def p(arr):
    ret = []
    #using visited boolean array to avoid duplicate traverse and backtracking.
    visited = [False] * len(arr)
    def dfs(start_idx, temp):
        ret.append(temp)
        for i in range(start_idx, len(arr)):
            if not visited[i]:
                visited[i] = True
                dfs(i + 1, temp + [arr[i]])  # i instead of start_idx
                visited[i] = False
    dfs(0, [])
    return ret
```

This now yields `visited` obsolete, so we can remove these checks:

```
def p(arr):
    ret = []
    def dfs(start_idx, temp):
        ret.append(temp)
        for i in range(start_idx, len(arr)):
            dfs(i + 1, temp + [arr[i]])
    dfs(0, [])
    return ret
```

That being said, I would suggest using `itertools.combinations`.